# Glassfy error: error (xcode): undefined symbol: _objc_class_$_glassfy FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?
Every time I try to compile for iOs it shows this error.

Glassfy error: error (xcode): undefined symbol: *objc_class*$_glassfy FLUTTER